# Sqlite Database : Id not auto incremented in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, auto-increment

I have created a local database in my APPlication. I am using SQLite database for the same. I have used 'id' as an auto-incremented column but the problem is that 'id' is not auto-incremented. It is always showing 0. I tried everything but all in vain. Please Help!!

Code:

```
StringBuilder ingredientsTable = new StringBuilder();
ingredientsTable.append("CREATE TABLE ");
ingredientsTable.append(TABLE_INGREDIENTS);
ingredientsTable.append(" ( ");
ingredientsTable.append(KEY_ING_ID);
ingredientsTable.append(" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ");
ingredientsTable.append(KEY_ING_NAME);
ingredientsTable.append(" TEXT, ");
ingredientsTable.append(KEY_ING_AMOUNT);
ingredientsTable.append(" TEXT ");
ingredientsTable.append(" ) ");
db.execSQL(ingredientsTable.toString());
```

Inserting Data to table

```
ModelInventory modelInventory = new ModelInventory();
modelInventory.setItemName(etItemName.getText().toString());
modelInventory.setItemAmount(Float.parseFloat(etAmount.getText().toString()));
modelInventory.setExpiryDate(etExpiryDate.getText().toString());
modelInventory.setRipeDate(etRipeDate.getText().toString());
modelInventory.setLocketQty(0);
dbHelper.addInventory(modelInventory);
```

Database Code:

```
public void addInventory(ModelInventory modelInventory) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_ITEM_ID, modelInventory.getItemId());
    newValues.put(KEY_ITEM_NAME, modelInventory.getItemName());
    newValues.put(KEY_ITEM_AMOUNT, modelInventory.getItemAmount());
    newValues.put(KEY_RIPE_DATE, modelInventory.getRipeDate().toString());
    newValues.put(KEY_EXPIRY_DATE, modelInventory.getExpiryDate().toString());
    newValues.put(KEY_IS_LOCKED_ITEM, modelInventory.getLockedItem());
    newValues.put(KEY_QTY_LOCKED, modelInventory.getLocketQty());

    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_INVENTORY, null, newValues);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}
```

Comment: maybe take some time and read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Answer (score 1):

First issue with your code is that for the creation of the table you use 3 variables for the names of the columns like: `KEY_ING_ID`, `KEY_ING_NAME` and `KEY_ING_AMOUNT`.
When you insert data to the table you use these column names: `KEY_ITEM_ID`, `KEY_ITEM_NAME`, `KEY_ITEM_AMOUNT`, `KEY_RIPE_DATE`, `KEY_EXPIRY_DATE`, `KEY_IS_LOCKED_ITEM` and `KEY_QTY_LOCKED`.
So how can you insert data to **a table with 3 columns** by **providing values to 7 columns** possibly with differemt names?
Second issue is that when you want a column to behave like `AUTO INCREMENT` then you must **not** assign a value to it when you insert a new row.
The system will provide that value.
So delete this line:

```
newValues.put(KEY_ITEM_ID, modelInventory.getItemId());
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to declare **Auto-Increment** in SqlLite as it is mentioned in SqlLite docs [see](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1).

> A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement.

**Update**

```
 newValues.put(KEY_ITEM_ID, modelInventory.getItemId());
```

here `modelInventory.getItemId()` **returns 0** (I am assuming you have declared ItemId as **Integer** in your **ModelInventory** class) So you need to pass null value instead (as per docs) like

```
 newValues.put(KEY_ITEM_ID,null);
```

Comment: how are you inserting data please paste that code too

Comment: dbHelper.addInventory(modelInventory); post code of this method. where actually data is being inserted into the sqlLite